# Can't get SSL to work with MassTransit and cloudamqp

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, masstransit, cloudamqp

I've been struggling to figure out how I'm meant to configure MassTransit and our new dedicated cloudamqp instance to work with SSL (note:everything is working without SSL fine).

I tried adding the UseSsl line in the code below, which I found in some old documentation, but that didn't work:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
          {
              var host = sbc.Host(new Uri(messageBusConfiguration["Host"]), h =>
              {
                   h.Username(messageBusConfiguration["Username"]);
                   h.Password(messageBusConfiguration["Password"]);
                   h.UseSsl(s => {});
               });
            });
```

In cloudamqp I've set it to allow ampqs too and my services/APIs are setup and running in IIS using HTTPs without any issues.

I suspect I'm missing something fundamental here but I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me, note that the port must be specified.

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
{
    var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://wombat.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5671/your_vhost/"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("your_username");
        h.Password("your_password");

        h.UseSsl(s =>
        {
            s.Protocol = SslProtocols.Tls12;
        });
    });

    x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "input_queue", e =>
    {
    });
});

await busControl.StartAsync(new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Token);

await busControl.StopAsync();
```

Comment: Side note, I just added automatic port selection for specifying `rabbitmqs` or `amqps` as the scheme on the URI, and automatic selection of SSL.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'm not sure I completely understand your comment about auto port selection though. Is this going to be in a later release? Does it mean I can just change the URI to be rabbitmqs://<cloudampqhost>/<vhost> without the port number?

Comment: Later release will have that but for now you need to specify the port.

Comment: Can I change the "rabbitmq://" scheme to amqp:// and still work?

Comment: Yes, it will work with either `amqp`, or use `amqps` for TLS.